# Code generation for mathematical problems

Tags: math, f#, code-generation, ocaml

I would like to write a program that takes in a description of a mathematical (optimization) problem, parses it, and generates compact, efficient C code that solves it.  I have a hacked up solution to a much smaller, more specific problem, in python, but it is ugly and just relies on templating the C code - so I have a whole mess of strings that look like

`for (k = 0; k <= %s; k += %s) a[k] = v[k]/%s * a[i];`

And then there is a mess of complex conditional logic, and at some point the above line gets written to solve_problem.c, after filling in the correct values of %s.

It actually gets much more complicated, because typically the problem is parameterized by matrices with certain structure, etc, and the approach above, while workable, is sort of starting to fall apart under its own weight.

So I suppose what I'm looking for is high-level advice on how to represent these sorts of problems in code, or rather just examples of other projects where this has been solved.  Someone told me to use OCaml or F# and look at FFTW, but something simpler would be appreciated.

I'm sorry for being so inarticulate, but it's difficult for me to even express what I'm looking for to myself, which is, I think, the root of the problem.

Comment: If you can, get a hold of [Numerica, A Modeling Language for Global Optimization](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/numerica). It'll give you good ideas!

Comment: You say "*So I suppose what I'm looking for is high-level advice on how to represent these sorts of problems in code,..*", but you never actually *describe* what "these sorts of problems" are.  The closest you come is the phase "mathematical (optimization) problem", and as a mathematician myself, that tells me almost nothing about what you are trying to do.  So please provide a more specific description of what types of problems you are trying to solve with your code generator.  Examples would be very helpful.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm trying to maximize a function, and there are constraints.  I don't feel as if the specifics really matter - I'm looking for high-level structural advice from someone who has done or thought about this sort of work.

Comment: This would be a good read I think: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87294/Symbolic-Calculation-in-F. Then you can convert the resulting expression into C code with templates.

Comment: @alex "I don't feel as if the specifics really matter". The specifics almost certainly matter. For example, you've quoted a line of code that could be unrolled by your compiler if the loop is short or could use different memory access patterns to improve spatial and temporal locality if the loop is long or the performance of the loop could be insignificant in which case you don't want to compile it to C.

Comment: @Jon Harrop I am still struggling with basic representational issues.  While the issues you mention are important and typical, I would rather decide on a framework that makes solving them natural, and not focus on how to solve them just yet, if that makes sense.  For now, one might assume that the implementation "space" is rather narrowly constrained - any natural method of writing the solver in C will, I hope, be fast and useful enough to make a good start.

Comment: @alex It is difficult to propose representations with so little information about what you are trying to represent.

Comment: Perhaps our [paper](http://ashishagarwal.org/2010/01/18/automating-mp-transformations/), in which we use programming language methods for optimization problems, will give you a good start. We don't go all the way to C, but the methodology of i) defining a language and ii) defining a compiler is essentially what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> for (k = 0; k <= %s; k += %s) a[k] = v[k]/%s * a[i];
> ```

You are asking for ways to represent code like the above. This could be represented by the value:

```
For("k", Int 0, Leq(Var "k", a), Set("k", Add(Var "k", b)),
    SetElt(Var "a", Var "k",
           Mul(Div(GetElt(Var "v", Var "k"), c, GetElt(Var "a", Var "i")))))
```

given a type like this:

```
type Expr =
  | Int of int
  | Var of string
  | Leq of Expr * Expr
  | Mul of Expr * Expr
  | Div of Expr * Expr
  | Set of string * Expr
  | SetElt of Expr * Expr * Expr
  | GetElt of Expr * Expr
  | For of string * Expr * Expr * Expr
```

I wrote a very simple high-level VM called HLVM that you might find enlightening because it uses such representations in a simple way. The definitions are [here](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/viewvc.php/hlvm.ml?view=markup&root=hlvm) and a bunch of tests written using those definitions are [here](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/viewvc.php/test.ml?view=markup&root=hlvm).

This representation is far more powerful than string munging because the pattern match compiler does exhaustiveness and redundancy checking for you, making it easy to write functions over values of this `Expr` type including optimization passes and code generators.

Comment: The beauty of this solution is that it makes it seem so trivial

Comment: Thank Jon for showing us a concrete piece of code, this is exactly the sort of thing he should be doing.

Comment: Nice.  Wish I could favorite answers ...

Comment: What language is that in (*.ml)?  Is that OCaml?

Comment: Ha, this seems fantastic!  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @RBarryYoung This is OCaml syntax that also works as-is in F# but the equivalent in Standard ML or Haskell is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to implement a compiler, and this is how you should approach your problem. There is an input language which describes your optimization problem, and the output language is C.

You can chop up your problem into the following tasks (not necessarily solved in this order):

1. Design a data structure which represents the [abstract syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax) for your input language.
2. Design a data structure which represents the abstract syntax of your output language, which in your case is (a subset of) C.
3. Design [concrete syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_syntax) of your input language.
4. Implement a lexer and a parser which converts concrete syntax to abstract syntax.
5. Implement a pretty printer which converts the abstract syntax of your output language to concrete syntax.
6. Implement a compiler which takes an optimization problem, expressed in abstract syntax, into the output, again expressed in abstract syntax.

If you are not used to implementing languages and compilers you will be tempted to take shortcuts. For example, you might consider parsing using regular expressions. Or you might think it is a good idea to skip the abstract syntax, and just generate the C source directly. I strongly advise against this. Abstraction is your friend because it will make your problem manageable.

You should carefully choose the language in which you will implement the whole thing. Of course, something like Ocaml is perfect for the job. But if you do not know Ocaml already, you should just stick to whatever language you are most comfortable with. You should not try to implement parsers by hand, there are plenty of parser generators out there. It is worth learning one. You may find my [PL Zoo](http://andrej.com/plzoo/) helpful.

Comment: While he may need various parsers to deal with the problem description, and I'm sympathetic to this point of view, the hard part of the problem as you identified it is step 6, about which you really didn't provide any insight.

Comment: How could I, I don't know what he's doing!?

Comment: This doesn't have to be an actual compiler. Imagine some function that parses an input string and decides which function to call based on this parsing. It may only need to act as an interface to some optimization library.

Comment: @Bitwise: that's exactly the sort of shortcut I would not recommend. If it is that easy, he should just define an Emacs macro for himself. And he already says in his question that he started with that sort of thing but it got too complicated.

Comment: @AndrejBauer the fact that it is not a new compiler does not mean this is necessarily a shortcut. Such a function (or set of functions) could be very sophisticated. There are several implementations of this type of functionality in various languages and this is usually treated as an added functionality rather than a new compiler.

Comment: @Bitwise: this discussion is pointless. And also, I suggest you read the question again and think about what he is asking for, and what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much background you have in optimization, but I doubt the path you described is the way to go. Specifically, I would be surprised if you could write efficient C code to solve optimization problems, unless you are restricting yourself to specific classes of problems. Optimization typically distinguishes between different types of problems (linear vs. non linear, integer vs continuous vs mixed-integer programming), which each typically use very different algorithms to solve the solution.

You might want to look into the [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003.aspx) for some ideas. Essentially, the MSF is a general API, which allows you to declare your problem in multiple forms (OML, a declarative language for specifying optimization problems, but also C# and F#), and then feeds the problem to the appropriate solver, given the nature of the problem.

Comment: I'm solving a fairly specific class of problems, and I'm familiar enough with it to write reasonably efficient codes that handle special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about simpler.  Suggest you look at existing work in mathematical modelling.  I wouldn't expect this to be simple; solver codes are difficult enough, and generating them is harder.

You need ways to specify the details of your problem, and means to assemble the parts of the answer controlled by these details.

I recommend:

[Sinapse](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/idbaxter/cs395T/papers/Kant94_Sinapse_00210600.pdf), a system for generating mathematical modelling codes; this paper talks about how the knowledge is organized and support the generation of finite-differencing codes,

and

[Solving finite differencing equations](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/35407/31359818.pdf?sequence=1), an MIT thesis in the same vein.

(I worked on the Sinapse system during its initial development).

Comment: Thanks for the references - the first one is dead; do you have an alternate URL?

Comment: I bungled the first one; link is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds that you want something like symbolic computation. Look into some implementations such as the following:

- [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/optim/symbolic_optim_demo.html)
- [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html)
- [TomSym](http://tomsym.com/index.html)
- [Python](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)

In general try looking at optimization packages, many support some kind of symbolic representations.

Comment: Presumably he is compiling to C for performance which rules out all of the above.

Comment: @Jonharrop I suggested he look at these to get an idea of implementation strategies, since many people have addressed this problem before.